# CAGradientLayer not fully clipping

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I created a `UIView` and added a `CAGradientLayer` to create a gradiented dot with a white border. What I have works so far, but it seems the gradient doesn't quite clip all the way and some still shows, here's what I mean:

[image: Bad] And this is what it should look like [image: Good].

Notice how there is no blue outline around the white border ^.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the view:

```
UIView *dot = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
dot.clipsToBounds = YES;

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = dot.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)UIColorFromRGB(0x03a69b).CGColor, (id)UIColorFromRGB(0x039976).CGColor];
gradient.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
gradient.borderWidth = 4.0;
gradient.cornerRadius = width/2.;

[dot.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

u can set the layer properties for `dot` view instead of setting to `gradient`
for example

```
UIView *dot = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 100, 100)];
dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//clearcolor
dot.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
dot.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.bounds.size.width/2.;
dot.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;

 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradient.frame = dot.bounds;
 gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,(id)   [UIColor greenColor].CGColor, nil];
//  gradient.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
//  gradient.borderWidth =5;
//  gradient.cornerRadius = dot.bounds.size.width/2.;
//  gradient.masksToBounds = YES;
    [dot.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    [self.view addSubview:dot];
```

Hope this helps u .. :)